# Calculating porcent in PHP giving wrong result

Tags: php

Here is the problem

I have 200 votes and 53 of them must be calculated as the porcent so I run this example to test the math first

```
$total="200";
$votes="53";
$calculate=($total / 100) * $votes;
echo "The porcent of votes is ".$calculate." ";
```

The result must be something like 26% but I get

Result 53% ...

What can be wrong ?

Comment: `$votes / $total * 100`

Comment: This has nothing to do with javascript, html or mysql...please tag questions according to actual problem

Comment: 200 divided by 100 is 2. And that times 53 is 106; something I'm not getting here

Comment: Charlotte solved the problem. Thanks a lot

Comment: off topic .. maths not programming question

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
<?php

$total="200";
$votes="53";
$calculate=($votes * 100) / $total;
echo "The porcent of votes is ".$calculate."%";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your calculate formula is wrong. If you want to calculate the percent of any number, you need the given or scored number and the total number. In your case, given is or score is 53 and total it 200. So you divide given or score by total and the multiply the results by 100 to get the percent. See below.

```
$total="200";
$votes="53";
$calculate=($votes / $total) * 100;
echo "The porcent of votes is ".$calculate." ";
```

Let me know if this helps. Stay warm!